# Can someone explain this project to me? Can you explain the schematic so I understand how it works?

Tags: ldr

https://electronicsprojectshub.com/how-to-make-an-automatic-night-light-using-ldr/

Can someone explain this project to me? Can you explain the schematic so I understand how it works? A very very simple explanation please. I will be starting my electronics degree soon and I just wanted to get ahead so assume I know nothing except the real bare basics.

Circuit:

[image]

Comment: The link you provided describes how the circuit works. Please ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to say "read the description on the page you linked to", but the description there is wrong. (don't believe everything you see on the Internet!)

An LDR will have a high resistance in the dark, and low in light.

If light hits the LDR, it will have a low resistance, pulling Q1's base up.  Q1 will turn on, pulling its collector, and Q2's base low, so Q2 will be off, and the relay will be released, turning the light off.

If the LDR is in the dark, it will have high resistance, allowing Q1 to turn off, so Q1's collector and Q2's base go high, pulling Q2's collector low and turning the relay on.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I recommend you is "test the LDR yourself". The internet is a good place to get ideas but I suggest you not to blindly follow those instructions.

In case of this project,the LDR explained totally wrong. Grab a LDR, a multimeter and measure its resistance in different lighting conditions.

In the circuit, I can see the transistor Q1 being operated in voltage divider configuration. The LDR and resistor R3 forms a voltage divider. So high resistance in LDR means higher drop in voltage at LDR which eventually means low voltage remaining for the R3 resistor. This voltage is also the base voltage. Lower base voltage means the transistor is in off state. So the transistor's collector is high (not due to weed). This  again implies that the base of Q2 is high and Q2 is switched on. So the collector is low and the relay is turned on.

In case the LDR drops low voltage, more of the supply voltage is remaining for the R3. This higher voltage across R3 causes base of Q1 to go high and Q1 is switched on. The collector of Q1 goes low and the base of Q2 is low. So, the transistor Q2 is switched off and the collector of Q2 goes high. The relay is now switched off.

After making this circuit and seeing the outcome, interchange the position of the LDR and R3 resistor. And see the outcome.